# IEEEtran in-text citations improperly formatted

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am trying to use the IEEEtran bibTeX style in a [custom thesis class found here](https://dotcio.rpi.edu/services/printing-publishing/thesis-preparation).

Instructions for using this class with bibTeX are given in [section 5.6.2 (page 7) of this document](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/docs/latex-thesis/rpithesis-doc.pdf)

I am using the `cite` package with the `noadjust` option, but the in text citations written as `\cite{reference1,reference2}` appear as [1,2] rather than IEEE style [1],[2]; and `\cite{reference3,reference4,reference5,reference6}` as [3-6] instead of [3]-[6].

What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[chap]{thesis}

\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

\begin{document}

\include{rpititle-phd}   % titlepage material for PhD thesis 
\include{rpiack}  % include for acknowledgements
\include{rpiabs} % abstract
\include{rpichap1} % chapter 1
\include{rpichap2} % chapter 2
\include{rpibib} % bibliography
\include{rpiapp} % appendix

\end{document}
```

MWE of rpibib.tex:

```
\specialhead{REFERENCES}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % specify bibliography style
\begin{singlespace}
\bibliography{myrefs.bib} % Prints the bibliography here, using "myrefs.bib"
\end{singlespace}
```

MWE of myrefs.bib

```
@article{thisbook,
author = {Kris Kringle and Nicholas, Saint},
title ={Methods for flight with reindeer power in non-aerodynamic bodies},
journal = {Journal of Holiday Science},
volume = {25},
number = {36},
pages = {32-39},
month = {Dec.},
year = {2019},
note ={PMID: 8907435},
doi = {10.4294/jhsc4302},
URL = {https://https://dotcio.rpi.edu/services/printing-publishing/thesis-preparation}
}

@article{anotherbook,
author = {Kris Kringle and Nicholas, Saint},
title ={Methods for flight with reindeer power in non-aerodynamic bodies},
journal = {Journal of Holiday Science},
volume = {25},
number = {36},
pages = {32-39},
month = {Dec.},
year = {2019},
note ={PMID: 8907435},
doi = {10.4294/jhsc4302},
URL = {https://https://dotcio.rpi.edu/services/printing-publishing/thesis-preparation}
}

@article{yetanotherbook,
author = {Kris Kringle and Nicholas, Saint},
title ={Methods for flight with reindeer power in non-aerodynamic bodies},
journal = {Journal of Holiday Science},
volume = {25},
number = {36},
pages = {32-39},
month = {Dec.},
year = {2019},
note ={PMID: 8907435},
doi = {10.4294/jhsc4302},
URL = {https://https://dotcio.rpi.edu/services/printing-publishing/thesis-preparation}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the custom thesis class was incomplete regarding definitions of citation punctuation.

Pasting the following from `IEEEtran.cls` into the `thesis.cls` file seems to have solved the problem:

```
%% CITATION AND BIBLIOGRAPHY COMMANDS
%% 
%% V1.6 no longer supports the older, nonstandard \shortcite and \citename setup stuff
% 
% 
% Modify Latex2e \@citex to separate citations with "], ["
\def\@citex[#1]#2{%
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{], [}%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\hbox{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}

% V1.6 we create hooks for the optional use of Donald Arseneau's
% cite.sty package. cite.sty is "smart" and will notice that the
% following format controls are already defined and will not
% redefine them. The result will be the proper sorting of the
% citation numbers and auto detection of 3 or more entry "ranges" -
% all in IEEE style:  [1], [2], [5]--[7], [12]
% This also allows for an optional note, i.e., \cite[mynote]{..}.
% If the \cite with note has more than one reference, the note will
% be applied to the last of the listed references. It is generally
% desired that if a note is given, only one reference is listed in
% that \cite.
% Thanks to Mr. Arseneau for providing the required format arguments
% to produce the IEEE style.
\def\citepunct{], [}
\def\citedash{]--[}
```

Comment: Loading the [`cite`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cite) package and using `\def\citepunct{], [}` and `\def\citedash{]--[}` should be sufficient.  These changes can be done in the tex document itself and do not require modifications to the class files.